# How do i send mp3 file with python using telegram bot

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram-bot

How can I send an MP3 audio file to a Telegram Bot using the open-source Python library [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

I wrote the following code:

```
URL = 'api.telegram.org/bot'+TOKEN+'/sendAudio'
af = open("temp.mp3", 'rb')
params = {'chat_id' : 421087308, 'audio' : af}
req = requests.post(URL, params)
af.close()
```

Comment: What is the error with the current code?

Comment: Using the [python telegram bot wrapper](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) you can easily do it using: `bot.send_audio(chat_id=chat_id, audio=open('tests/test.mp3', 'rb'))`

Comment: Did the above code work?

Comment: Yes, this code work

Comment: Then, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the [python telegram bot wrapper](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) you can easily do it using:

```
bot.send_audio(chat_id=chat_id, audio=open('tests/test.mp3', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 3):

`python-telegram-bot` can be redundant if you need a bot for a single action like sending `mp3` file. So if you want to send the file by using the `requests` library, you can use following snippet:

```py
with open('tests/test.mp3', 'rb') as audio:
    payload = {
        'chat_id': TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID,
        'title': 'file.mp3',
        'parse_mode': 'HTML'
    }
    files = {
        'audio': audio.read(),
    }
    resp = requests.post(
        "https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendAudio".format(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN),
        data=payload,
        files=files).json()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this cammand**:

```
update.message.reply_audio(audio='https://audio_link.mp3')
```